# Unique page identifiers in Grav CMS

Tags: twig, yaml, grav

I'm using the Grav CMS to create a modular web page; however, I'm having difficulty customizing the layout based on how the content is generated.

I've followed the documentation found Grav main site from which I've model my site after.

My folder structure is essentially:

```
pages
    01.home
         _section1
         _section2
```

In each section folder I have my .md file. And each section is considered a sub-page of 'home'.

I've created the template file, modular.html.twig, in which I have the following code:

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
{% for child in page.children() %}
    {{ child.content() }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

This code iterates through sub-pages to load the content onto the home page. In my template I'm simply printing the result of the content using `{{ content }}`

What I end up with is a page with vertically stacked content and repeating html,
[as such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzNvA.png).

What I want to do is uniquely define each sub-page (section) so that I can manipulate the content differently in my html, [as such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhWtf.png).

I've thought about creating separate template files for each section, but much of my content is nested.

For instance I have something akin to:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="section-1">
      <h1>{{ content }}</h1>  <!--Needs to be unique-->
   </div>
   <div class="section-2">
      <h1>{{ content }}</h1>  <!--Needs to be unique-->
   </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do with this framework? If so, how might I go about it?

Thank you

Comment: I was looking for a way to do this also. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many ways to do this. For me, I use page's header to set CSS class of each section.

My section's md files could look like this (for example mysection.md)

```
---
title: Section 1
section_class: section-1
---
This is the content of section 1.
```

Here is my modular.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    {% for child in page.children() %}
    <div class="{{ child.header.section_class }}">
        {{ child.content() }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

In my mysection.html.twig I print the section's content

```
<h1>{{ page.content }}</h1>
```

I hope this helps.